# Model parameter not recognized by controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a model called PostUserAccount, and I'm trying to use it in an ApiController as a parameter the way it normally is when you generate a controller with read/write actions, using Entity Framework

Example generated by controller generator:

```
    // POST api/Profile
    public HttpResponseMessage PostUserProfile(UserProfile userprofile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.UserProfiles.Add(userprofile);
          ...etc
```

code that I'm working with:

```
    // POST gamer/User?email&password&role
    public HttpResponseMessage PostUserAccount(PostAccountModel postaccountmodel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

         if (postaccountmodel == null) return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "model is null");

        ...etc
```

for whatever reason, the postaccountmodel is null in this case, and running this api command returns "model is null". any ideas?

Here is the model in question

```
public class PostAccountModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Role { get; set; }

    public string Avatar { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would be interesting to look at your model code. Also, you might simply providing bad JSON and your model can't get hydrated. Your problem most likely somewhere in the client side

Comment: I added the model code to the Q

Comment: The comment above your action method looks more like a get request with queryparams rather than a post. How are you calling to the API?

Comment: You can still post with query strings. Its just an odd scenario if you do. I'm not sure how the model binder/formatters would handle this. But seeing an example post, like something from fiddler, would be helpful.

Comment: the command look like this: POST /gamer/user?email=blahBlahBlah&password=blahBlahBlah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to send the model in the URI query string. Problems:

1. Your query string is not well formed - should be ?Email=xxx&Password=xxx& ...
2. You need to decorate the postaccountmodel parameter with the [FromUri] attribute, to tell Web API to bind the model from the URI

Another option is to send the model in the request body as JSON or XML. I'd recommend that, especially if you're really sending a password in the request. (And use SSL!)

This topic describes parameter binding in Web API: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: My query string does have that form, however, your second suggestion solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the [FromBody] attribute in front of your postaccountmodel parameter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: [FromBody] is the opposite, it tells Web API to read the model from the request body.